# Email Parsing Cloud Service

Tags: web-services, email, rest, service, cloud

I was looking for a cloud email service that offered the following:

- Garauntee deliveribility of emails
- Have the ability to parse an email and post accordingly to a HTTP endpoint

I swear I had seen a service like this, but I can't seem to relocate it.

**Any chance somebody knows of any other services that fit my description?**

I found a service called mailgun, but it doesn't do email parsing.  I also know of Amazon's email service as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by parse? Do you mean parse the POP3 message format into some structured format like XML?

Comment: parse as in, there are defined structures within the email that are can be converted into a corresponding form post or JSON object.

Comment: I also found SendGrid and it looks like they have a POST api

Comment: For those that do find this a constructive question, Google App Engine can be configured to accept incoming email. Then some python or java coding can be done to parse the email and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://cloudmailin.com allows you to receive email. It can do the parsing and http delivery but does not handle sending of email.

Answer (score 7):

Mailgun does parse emails: http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#receiving-messages

Answer (score 0):

I see this question has been answered. But I encourage future readers to check out **http://getdispatch.com**.

Not only can emails be parsed and outputted to HTTP(Webhook), but Dispatch can also output to SMS, Email, Voice, and can also be pointed at other 3rd party services such as Mailchimp, Highrise, Zendesk, etc.