# IMAP IDLE monitoring service with http callback?

Tags: php, api, email, imap, saas

I have a small web app which polls an IMAP mailbox (via PHP's imap module) every minute via a cronjob. I'd like to make this more realtime, as the maximum 1 minute lag is unacceptable in some cases.

Is there a service out there that will connect to an IMAP mailbox, use IMAP IDLE to constantly monitor for messages, then POST exhaustive message data (headers, content) to a URL? Sort of like Twilio does with incoming phone calls?

Comment: For reference of others who are searching, [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511412/email-parsing-cloud-service) has some suggestions.  Namely, [cloudmailin](http://cloudmailin.com/) and [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a service that you describe, but I suggest simply turning the script you already have into a daemon.

If you wanted, you could do this yourself using the [PCNTL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php).  Instead, I utilize a class that has everything all set up and ready to go:

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Using that class, you can create a "daemonized" version of your script fairly easily:

```
require_once "System/Daemon.php";                 // Include the Class
System_Daemon::setOption("appName", "mydaemon");  // Minimum configuration
System_Daemon::start();                           // Spawn Deamon!
```

*(Sample code from the page with the daemon class)*

Comment: Interesting. We're hoping to stay away from running any daemons on our own infrastructure to do this, as we often don't have system-level access (rather, just git r/w and database) to servers.

Comment: @obrienmd, I suspect buying hosting that allows you to run a daemon will be cheaper than something that posts e-mails from IMAP to you, if it exists.

Comment: It's not really a question of money. Our dev / staging / production workflow is really clean and simple. Complexity is our worst enemy.